# Trying to run "ruby app.rb", but can not load oauth2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Complete beginner to programming here. I'm trying to run `ruby app.rb` and I get the following error:

```
       /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- oauth2 (LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/dankearns/projects/wgc_groundwork/lib/profile.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from app.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

This is really driving me insane. I've tried a number of fixes but not seem to work. Can anyone help?

Comment: Looks like you're missing a gem or two- what are the require statements at the start of your `app.rb` file?

Comment: require 'sinatra'
require './lib/profile'

But I've checked and I think I have sinatra?

Comment: @glenatron I'm not sure where to go from here

Comment: Do you also have `oauth2`?

Comment: I tried installing but I get...

        Daniels-MacBook-Pro:~ dankearns$ gem install oauth2
Fetching: multipart-post-2.0.0.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/multipart-post-2.0.0
Daniels-MacBook-Pro:~ dankearns$

Answer (score 1):

> ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES) Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/multipart-post-2.0.0

You're trying to install code into your Apple-installed Ruby.

Don't do that.

Instead, use [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) or [RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) to install Ruby in a sandbox, which you can then play with to your heart's content. If you go with RVM, read the installation page completely. People failing to do what that page says, or what RVM says after it's on the disk, results in one of the top RVM problems on Stack Overflow.

Apple installed theirs for their convenience and it's OK for us to use it, but changing it can lead to problems, especially if you remove something it or some other app needs.